# Unable to access files on Segate external USB hard drive

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive

I have segate HD, i m able to connect it to ubuntu 18.04 but when i try to access file it hangs my system, and if i try to access it from CLI getting below error on **ls** command.

> ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with more specific detail. For example is the external drive mounted and if so how? in `fstab` or from `Nautilus`. If `fstab` show your entry. How is it "connected" ?

Comment: Try the "disks" program and do a smart test on drive.  So far it sounds like a bad drive or maybe a bad connection.  Does drive have external power source or is it powered by USB?

Comment: @crip659 Yes this is external USB HDD